# Typescript Map Record of Arrays to Record of Records

Tags: typescript

I have type which consists of fields with specified arrays? For example:

```
type ApiResponse = {
    audios?: AudioType[];
    albums?: AlbumType[];
    // ...
    users?: UserType[];
    videos?: VideoType[];
}
```

where types AudioType, AlbumType (...) have field id (string).
I can't change it.

If I use `typeof keyof` and `reduce` it will give `Record<string, AudioType | AlbumType | ...>

How can I automatically transform it to something like this:

```
type IndexedResponse = {
    audios?: Record<string, AudioType>;
    albums?: Record<string, AlbumType>;
    // ...
    users?: Record<string, UserType>;
    videos?: Record<string, VideoType>;
}
```

Comment: `type IndexedResponse = { [K in keyof ApiResponse]: Record<string, ApiResponse[K][number]> }`

Comment: @vr. Type 'number' cannot be used to index type 'ApiResponse[K]'

Comment: ```type IndexedResponse = { [K in keyof ApiResponse]: Record<string, Required<ApiResponse>[K][number]> }``` is ok

Comment: Right, since it could be `undefined`. That makes sense.